# Error querying SQL SELECT in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to connect to and select data from an PostgreSQL server. I am able to connect to the server but my select query appears to be running an error. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

$conn = "host=#### port=5432 dbname=consolidated user=#### password=####";

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$dbconn = pg_connect($conn);

$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT id FROM retailer_retailer;");
if (!$result) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "ID: $row[0]";
  echo "<br />\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: The semi-colon is unnecessary, but try checking for [pg_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) when your query fails.

Comment: @aynber I tried `echo pg_last_error($result);` but nothing came up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss the schema name right here, I assume you have table in public schema and your query should like-

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT id FROM public.retailer_retailer;");
```

If you have another schema then you can replace public with other schema name

Comment: let me know whether it works for you or not, if worked accept it as answer

Comment: @veshar_joshi I am trying to link to a public scheme but this still doesn't work

Comment: did you get any erroor